# Opening a Silverlight Window From Javascript and passing an object

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, silverlight

I am looking for a way to open my silverlight application from my web application using javascript.  I will also need to pass a string to the silverlight application during this process.  The code below will currently open the silverlight application for me.  I need to know how to do this while passing in the string value to silverlight.

```
$(function () {
$('.cell').on('focus', 'textarea', function () {
    var inputValue = $(this).val();     
    window.open('/TestPage.aspx');
});
```

});

Note:  I have searched everywhere for the answer to this and cant seem to find a decent solution.  All of the demos I've found are incomplete or do not function as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it in the query string:

```
window.open('/TestPage.aspx?input=' + inputValue);
```

Retrieve it in Silverlight using `HtmlDocument.QueryString`:

```
string inputValue = null;
if (HtmlDocument.QueryString.ContainsKey("input"))
    inputValue = HtmlDocument.QueryString["input"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I meant to mention that a query string is not an option.  I am passing an rtf string which has too many symbols.

Comment: @nsmanners are you sure?  You can always url-encode the string, and you're allowed up to 2,000 characters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string

Comment: @nsmanners if it's too long, then you could always use an Ajax post instead.

Comment: I am afraid several of the rtf strings will have well over 2000 characters.  Would you happen to have an example of how to open a silverlight window while utilizing ajax?

Comment: @nsmanners my mistake, I meant use a regular form post, not an Ajax one -- send the string as an HTTP Post parameter to "TestPage.aspx", where you retrieve it using `Request.Params`, and add it to the Silverlight `initParams`.